Euler's Totient function
This is my first question in stack exchange so I could not think of a specific title.
Calculate the smallest value of X such that $\phi(X)  =10^8$ where $\phi$ is the Euler's Totient Function.
I started by taking X = $2^a.5^b.p_1.p_2...p_k$ where $k \geq 1$ and $p_i = 2^{a_i}.5^{b_i}+1$ is prime $\forall$ $1\leq i \leq k$.
I'm unable to move further from this step. Can you please help me?

Can you solve for $a$ and $b$ when $k = 0$?  (No one said you must have larger primes in the factorization of $X$.)  If you take $k = 1$ and $p_1 = 11$, you get one factor of $2$ and one factor of $5$ in the totient, so you can reduce $a$ and $b$ by one each; does this give you a smaller $X$ or did the $+1$ in $11 = 10+1$ cause $X$ to be bigger?  Does the same sort of thing happen for other primes of the form $2^{a_i} 5^{b_i}+1$?

If $k=0$, $a=7$ and $b=9$, then $X = 2^75^9$. But can we conclude that we always get a number larger than this when you take larger primes?

It seems to be a good try to assume that $X=pq$ with two bigger primes, where $10^8=\phi(X)=(p-1)(q-1)$. This yields an example with $X=10^8+64101$, which is much smaller than $X=2^7\cdot 5^9$.

The answer of WolframAlpha is $X=1601*62501=100064101$

This can also be found by looking into https://oeis.org/A072075 .

I have got the answer for this question. Thank you for the clarification in the comments. I have been trying to check for the numbers of the form $X = 2^a.5^b$ and $X = 2^a.5^b.p_1.p_2...p_k$ but I didn't get the idea to check the numbers of the form $X=p_1.p_2..p_k$. If we do so, we'll get the minimum as $X = (40^2+1).(250^2+1)$ (check comments for more clarification). Thank you everyone who have helped me solve this question.
